# Get minimum unique tuple pair from list of tuples

Tags: python, tuples

Consider the following list of tuples:

```
transactions = [
    ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-29'),
    ('SNOW', '2022-04-26'),
    ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'),
    ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'),
    ('MSFT', '2022-04-11'),
    ('MSFT', '2022-04-21'),
    ('SHOP', '2022-04-25')
]
```

I can get the tuple with the minimum date like this:

```
min(transactions, key=lambda x: x[1])
```

This returns a single tuple:

```
('MSFT', '2022-04-11')
```

I need to return the minimum date of any duplicates along with all unique values. So my output should be this:

```
[
    ('SNOW', '2022-04-26'),
    ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'),
    ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'),
    ('MSFT', '2022-04-11'),
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution 1:

```
min_dates = {}
for item in transactions:
    key, date = item
    if key not in min_dates or date < min_dates[key]:
        min_dates[key] = date
result = [(key, min_dates[key]) for key in min_dates]
result.sort(key=lambda x: x[1])
```

[image]

Solution 2:

```
from itertools import groupby
# Sort transactions by key and then by date
sorted_transactions = sorted(transactions)

# Group transactions by key
grouped_transactions = groupby(sorted_transactions, key=lambda x: x[0])

# Construct final list of tuples with the minimum date for each key
result = [(key, min(group, key=lambda x: x[1])[1]) for key, group in grouped_transactions]

#print(result)
# Prints : [('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'), ('MSFT', '2022-04-11'), ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'), ('SNOW', '2022-04-26')]
```

Comment: For solution 2, that `key=lambda x: (x[0], x[1])` is what would already happen by default if you didn't specify a key.

Comment: @NikT , I have checked and you were right, that was an embarrassing mistake on my part, altough I have edited the code now. Thank you for bringing this to my attention :)

Comment: `result = [next(group) for _, group in grouped_transactions]`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to just do:

```
output = dict(reversed(sorted(transactions)))
output = list(output.items())
```

`sorted` can automatically handle tuples, and since you want the minimum, you can use `reversed` (instead of specifying a `key=lambda ...`).

Since your dates are `yyyy-mm-dd`, the string sorting should be correct.

This is creating a dict, and overwriting each key with the lesser sorted value as it gets to it.

Answer (score 0):

My plan is to create a dictionary `{name: date}` where the date is the smallest (or earliest) for the corresponding name.

```py
transactions = [
    ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-29'),
    ('SNOW', '2022-04-26'),
    ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'),
    ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'),
    ('MSFT', '2022-04-11'),
    ('MSFT', '2022-04-21'),
    ('SHOP', '2022-04-25')
]

earliest = {}
for name, date in transactions:
    earliest.setdefault(name, date)
    if earliest[name] > date:
        earliest[name] = date
out = list(earliest.items())
```

`out` then is:

```py
[('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'),
 ('SNOW', '2022-04-26'),
 ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'),
 ('MSFT', '2022-04-11')]
```

Notes

- The `setdefault` method is the magic: if the key does not exist in the dictionary, it will insert the key/value into the dictionary. If the key does exist, it will not insert (do nothing).
- After set default, I will update the value only when it is smaller
- Once I built the dictionary, calling `list(...items())` will get our result.
- This function does not alter `transactions` in any way.

Answer (score 0):

With out thinking too hard, my gut reaction led me to the following solution below. Note, I do not claim this to be optimal.

```
# Import pandas to leverage built-in query methods
import pandas as pd

# Define the test data, list of tuples
transactions = [ ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-29'),
                 ('SNOW', '2022-04-26'),
                 ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'),
                 ('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'),
                 ('MSFT', '2022-04-11'),
                 ('MSFT', '2022-04-21'),
                 ('SHOP', '2022-04-25') ]

# Convert the test data into a pandas dataframe, columns can be named anything
df = pd.DataFrame( transactions, columns=[ 'Symbol', 'Date' ] )

# Convert the Date column into proper dates, very powerful option going forward
df[ 'Date' ] = pd.to_datetime( df[ 'Date' ] )

# Group the dataframe by the unique values in the Symbol column and reduce to instances where the minimum value appears in the Date column for a given unique value of the Symbol column
df = df.groupby( 'Symbol' ).apply( lambda x: x.loc[ x.Date.idxmin() ] ).reset_index( drop=True )

# Optional, convert the dataframe back into a list of tuples, maintains dates as Timestamps for future leveraging of pandas built in methods for date/time data
transactions = list( df.itertuples( index=False, name=None ) )
```

If you print the variable `df` after its last assignment, then you will get:

```
print(df)
    Symbol       Date
0  GBP.USD 2022-04-27
1     MSFT 2022-04-11
2     SHOP 2022-04-21
3     SNOW 2022-04-26
```

If you print the variable `transactions` after its last assignment, then you will get:

```
print(transactions)
[('GBP.USD', Timestamp('2022-04-27 00:00:00')), ('MSFT', Timestamp('2022-04-11 00:00:00')), ('SHOP', Timestamp('2022-04-21 00:00:00')), ('SNOW', Timestamp('2022-04-26 00:00:00'))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` like below

```
import pandas as pd
list(pd.DataFrame(transactions).groupby(0).min().itertuples(name=None))
```

which should give

```
[('GBP.USD', '2022-04-27'),
 ('MSFT', '2022-04-11'),
 ('SHOP', '2022-04-21'),
 ('SNOW', '2022-04-26')]
```